# Converting for each loop to for loop java while reading csv data java

Tags: java, csv, readfile, csvreader

**I have the following code:**

```
    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
            r.forEach(x -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));
        }
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MarioVarchmin He is compiling on old android sdk I guess

Comment: @Husseinfo this likely has *nothing* to do with android or any of it's SDKs though. could be a plain java "question" too.

Comment: @Shark Yes it could be a simple java program too, why did you get that offended!
I had a similar experience when I wasn't able to use Collections' forEach. Keep relaxed dude.

Comment: @Husseinfo there was no offense, i was just stating that as it is, this question looks nothing like it has anything to do with android.

Comment: @Shark Yeah right, but there is a possibility though....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))) {
       List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
       for(int i =0;i< r.size() ; i++){
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r.get(i));
       }
    }
```

Another Solution :

```
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file))) {
   List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();
   for(String[] x : r){
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String[] s: r) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
}
```